# How do I figure out what to import from PyQt4 specifically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am trying to import the minimum of what I need from PyQt4.

The two things I'm actually using are QApplication and QFileDialog.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
from PyQt4.QtGUI import *
```

Is there a better, more minimal way, since I'm only using those 2 things?

Comment: yes you should import elements naming them `from MyModule import element1, element2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To import only `QApplication` and `QFileDialog` you should do:

```
from PyQt4.QtGUI import QApplication, QFileDialog
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, when I tried just importing QApplication, it was giving me an error.

Comment: @mauve you're welcome! If it's the expected answer you can accept it ([see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png))

Comment: I know, I was waiting for the timer to let me!